# Read about a word for someone who prefers isolation and educating themselves on wikipedia, cant remember it

Tags: single-word-requests

I read an page on wikipedia. It was a classification of a person, or something like that. I think it described someone who prefers isolation and reading / educating themselves over more common behaviors. I think it was perhaps Psychology related. I think it was presented in a positive light rather than a disorder. It was a very interesting and relateable, I'd like to find that wikipedia page again. Anyone know?

Comment: an 'introvert'?

Comment: nope it was much scientific word

Answer (score 2):

How about [**autodidact**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism)?  The Wikipedia article is extensive.

Comment: Its close, I can't remember very clearly unfortunately. I think the one I read had more a more personality trait theme to it.

Comment: @meffect then you can have a fun next few hours trying to find it! :)

Comment: @meffect Maybe it's at link from the article.  One of the famous autodidacts, perhaps?  Best of luck!